# Implementing Java Threads for selenium Grid

Tags: junit4, selenium-grid

I have Used Junit to create Testcases and now i want to execute my testcases parallely using Selenium Grid with the help of Threads.

```
package com.eviltester.seleniumtutorial;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Myseleniumtests extends SeleneseTestCase implements Runnable
{
----
some code
----
}
```

The error what i m getting is:

> The return types are incompatible for
>   the inherited methods Runnable.run(),
>   TestCase.run()

can anyone pls suggest me how to run multiple testcases parallely using selenium Grid & JUnit.

Comment: Please read the introductory material of the technologies involved. This combination simply does not mix together.

Comment: I'm not really sure what introductory materials you're referring to.  This is simply a case of a class and an interface defining a method with the same name.  Naturally Myseleniumtests can't have both definitions since they differ only in return type.  An intro Java book would help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using [parallel-junit](http://java.net/projects/parallel-junit).  Although I doubt that using SeleneseTestCase on grid is going to work for you.  I haven't actually tried it, but it's not something I'm aware of any dev actually working on.